# jquery » check id of div and don't allow show if same id of other displayed

Tags: jquery, hide, show, show-hide

I have this code:

```
checkbox : function(elem) {
$(function() {
    var isChecked = elem.checked,
        $check = $(this).val(),
        $address = $('.'+ elem.id);
        $image = $('.imagenone');
    if(isChecked) {     
            $address.stop().fadeIn("slow").css("display","inline-block");
            $image.stop().fadeOut("slow").css("display","none");
    } else {
            $address.stop().fadeOut("slow");
    }
});
}
```

---

I need check if id of "$address"(class) displayed, not display other div with same id.

[IMAGE](http://s30.postimg.org/p0j37jl01/coding.jpg)

Comment: You should never have 2 matching ids on the same page.  The whole point of an id is that is unique.

Comment: I have a "query" which lists all the "rows" of the table, each "row" has a sub-category and associated product, which in my case the sub-category is the class and id is the product. but for different sub-categories can have the same product, not wanting to give the same id / product appear in duplicate.
(sorry my english)

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
if($address.visible(true).length>0){
    if(isChecked) {     
        $address.stop().fadeIn("slow").css("display","inline-block");
        $image.stop().fadeOut("slow").css("display","none");
    } else {
        $address.stop().fadeOut("slow");
    }
}
```

Comment: does not work. and also to emphasize that I intend not to repeat, is different "class" with the same id. look see image to the structure in order to get to be as clear as possible.
[Image]: http://s30.postimg.org/p0j37jl01/coding.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `value` of your checkbox instead of the id.

Then you can use:

```
myVal = $(this).val();
$address = $('.'+myVal);
```

Comment: the problem is that there are only checkboxes for sub-categories, where the purpose is to create a filter. where all products with this sub-category, choosing more than one sub-category to check the sub-category appear. In different sub-category may contain the same products, just wanting to appear only once, and not repeated, ie not appear divs with the same id (same product) in duplicate.